# Parsing through json data and printing the results

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Parsing through json data and printing the results:

JSON FEED:

```
{
    "data": [   
        {  
            "url": "http://test.com",
            "source": 2,
            "created": 144139828328,
            "user_id": 1238,
            "visible": 1,
            "comments": "hello",
            "author": "{\"name\":\"johndoe\",\"link\":\"http://url.com/johndoe\",\"picture\":\"//url.com/imageurl.jpg\",\"username\":\"johndoe21\",\"fullname\":\"John Doe\"}",
            "post_id": "user_1238"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the initial code for parsing:

```
dynamic outputArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
dynamic Data = outputArray.data;
foreach (var jsonDataVal in Data)
{
    s = s + "url: " + jsonDataVal.url;
    s = s + "source: " + jsonDataVal.source;
}
```

I need to get the author data, but unable to get it.. jsonDataVal.author.name is not working.

Then I did this:

```
dynamic outputArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
dynamic Data = outputArray.data;
foreach (var jsonDataVal in Data)
{
    s = s + "url: " + jsonDataVal.url;
    s = s + "source: " + jsonDataVal.source;

    //obtained author data into string and applied JsonConvert.DeserializeObject
    string author = Data.author
    dynamic outputArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(author);

    var authdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(author);   

    s = s + "author name: " + authdata.name;
    //not working   
}
```

How can I get the data from author fields `author.name`, `author.link`, `author.picture`?

Comment: "JSON" provided as a "JSON FEED" is invalid. It is being parsed properly without errors?

Comment: yes, I was able to parse without errors, except the author data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could ditch the `dynamic` and use types from JSON.NET instead.
Also, you could write a method that you call recursively to get all of the properties of given JSON object.

```
// your "main" method
private void Parse(string json) // <- pass in your JSON as string
{
    string properties = string.Empty;

    // parse JSON onbject
    JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
    // get an array, which is token called "data"
    JArray data = jsonObject.SelectToken("data").Value<JArray>();

    // iterate over all tokens in data array (in this case just one)
    foreach (JToken token in data.Children())
    {
        // get names and values of all properties within current token 
        foreach (JProperty property in token.Children<JProperty>())
            properties += GetProperty(property);
    }

    // print out results
    Console.WriteLine(properties);
}
```

---

```
// method extracting property name & value
private string GetProperty(JProperty property, string prefix = null)
{
    string value = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        // if property value is another object, call method recursively
        var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(property.Value.ToString());
        foreach (JProperty innerProperty in jsonObject.Children<JProperty>())
            value += GetProperty(innerProperty, property.Name);  

    }
    catch (JsonReaderException)
    {
        // else just format return value
        value = string.Format(@"{0}:{1}{2}", 
            prefix != null ? string.Format("{0} {1}", prefix, property.Name) : property.Name, 
            property.Value, 
            Environment.NewLine);
    }
    return value;
}
```

---

In your case above would spit out the following.

> url:http://test.com
>   source:2
>   created:144139828328
>   user_id:1238
>   visible:1
>  
>   comments:hello
>   author name:johndoe
>   author link:http://url.com/johndoe
>   author picture://url.com/imageurl.jpg
>   author username:johndoe21
>   author fullname:John Doe
>   post_id:user_1238

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `author` object is not an array. You parse it twice while it is a simple JSON object stored as a string. Moreover, in your JSON example, author belongs to an array item; however, for some reason, you try to extract if from `Data` object:

```
string author = Data.author; // not jsonDataVal.author
```

It works well for me:

```
dynamic outputArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
dynamic Data = outputArray.data;
foreach (var jsonDataVal in Data)
{
    s = s + "url: " + jsonDataVal.url;
    s = s + "source: " + jsonDataVal.source;

    //obtained author data into string and applied JsonConvert.DeserializeObject
    dynamic authorData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonDataVal.author.ToString());

    s = s + "author name: " + authorData.name;
}
```

Note that `.ToString()` is required in order to convert `JValue` to `String`.

Comment: Hi Yelder, it is still not showing any output. jsonDataVal.url works but authorData.name is not working.

string author = Data.author; // not jsonDataVal.author
I can't use this because Data contains more than one objects(I showed only one as an example)

Comment: Why `Data.author`? Check my code. It is `jsonDataVal.author` because it is an enumerated array item. It definitely does work, I have checked it twice.